# floating elements <br clear="both"/> in a better css way?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a few floating elements like a sidebar that floated besides a content area. If I don't add a `<br clear="both"/>` at the end of the sidebar, then footer and parts of the background get floated weird.

Any quick solution I missed to think of?

Thank you.

**Edit:** For example, I want the borders to have no gaps and the backgrounds should have no spaces either. Should just look like two sections: 1) content with sidebar 2) footer

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>layout</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #main {
        background:#cfcfcf;
    }

    .inner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 96px 72px 0;
        width: 1068px;
        border-color: #000;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 1px;
        color: #3C3C3C;
    }

    .post {
        width: 705px;
        background:#999;
        float:left;
    }

    #comments, #respond {
        background:#999;
    }

    #sidebar {
        background:#777;
    }

    #footer {
        clear:both;
        background:gray;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div class="inner">

            <div id="post" class="post">

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Test Page</h2>

                <div class="entry">

                    <p>Lorem ipsum sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

                </div> <!-- entry -->

            </div> <!-- post -->

            <div id="sidebar">

                <h2>Meta</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Login</li>
                        <li>Anything</li>
                    </ul>

                <h2>Subscribe</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Entries (RSS)</li>
                        <li>Comments (RSS)</li>
                    </ul>

            </div> <!-- sidebar -->

        </div> <!-- inner -->

    </div> <!-- main -->

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="inner">

        Something

        </div> <!-- inner -->
    </div> <!-- footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your HTML and CSS code for the divs?

Comment: Good article: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the containing elements `overflow` property to something other than `visible`.

Comment: it worked if i set the .inner div to overflow:hidden! i wonder if it also works in ie

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I wouldn't try to get around it.  You could put the clear in the footer as other people have suggested; but you aren't guaranteed that other parts of your html won't be improperly floated or blocked.  If you adopt a policy of only clearing elements when they mess up due to floats in a random part of your html; you might make the habit of always doing that.  Instead, the following is an example of a style which usually guarantees that other elements won't be improperly floated:

```
<div>
  <div style="float:right;"></div>
  <div style="float:right;"></div>
  <!--Add a clear div as last sibling of any floated elements-->
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Also, I would use a empty div instead of br.  Thats just me though.

So drawing from your example:

```
        </div> <!-- post -->

        <!-- insert empty clear div hear -->
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        <div id="sidebar">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the footer so it has a style with `clear: both`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to clear the left and right for the next element.

So on the footer you could add:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
}
```

This would force the footer to go down to the next line, and it is the 'proper' way. It will also be easier to change your design later because you won't have to go change markup, just the CSS.

Comment: i edited my post. please have a look. how would you solve it in this case. a simple clear:both doesn't do the job ... the background and the border is buggy

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` is really nice. Too bad IE doesn't really support it.